# How to sort Pandas df columns' values based on its position not labels?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

There must be an obvious answer but I could neither find it in the sort_values()'s [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)  nor in related questions posts*

`by` in `df.sort_values()` accept columns labels, but **How do I sort using the columns' position** ?

I came up with this cumbersome code

`df.iloc[df.iloc[:,1].sort_values().index]`

to sort on the second column.

I was thinking that something like `df.sort_values(by=1,axis=1)` would exist.  So what is syntacticly simple and correct way to do that ?

---

*Related questions: [1](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37287938/sort-pandas-dataframe-by-value), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618981/how-to-sort-pandas-data-frame-using-values-from-several-columns), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37804702/how-to-sort-pandas-dataframe-non-lexical), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46584016/sort-pandas-dataframe-by-column), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46584016/sort-pandas-dataframe-by-column), [6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45736127/pandas-dataframe-ordering-and-sorting-of-column-values)

Comment: Could you provide example data?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand.  ```df.iloc[:, np.argsort(df.columns.values)]``` will reorder the columns in the df, right ?  What I need is to sort the df on, for example, the 33th column's values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simpliest is select columns names by position:

```
df = df.sort_values(df.columns[1])
```

Comment: yes !  I see.  No shorter hand then ?  Why not allowing positional int as a ```by``` value ?

Comment: In my opinion it is not implemented yet.